# Get labeled alternative name in ANTLR RuleContext

Tags: javascript, antlr, antlr4

Is there any way to obtain the matched labeled alternative name in a `RuleContext`?

ex.:

```
myRule:
   foo # fooRule
   | bar # barRule
;
```

I want to get `"fooRule"`/`"barRule"` from the `RuleContext`

I have a large grammar that I'm developing a Visitor to, so I built a tool to help me visualize the result from the Visitor methods being implemented and also which ones are missing (since the default implementation for every Visitor method is to call `visitChildren(ctx)`, I've overriden `visitChildren` to return a "Not implemented: {ruleName}" message.

The ANTLR generated Visitor code generates specific `RuleContexts` (in the example above, `FooRuleContext` and `BarRuleContext`) for labeled alternatives and creates Visitor methods for those alternatives (`visitFooRule` and `visitBarRule`), but the underlying ruleIndex for those contexts is still the parent rule (in this case, `myRule`).

I can´t find in the generated parse tree or any of the API classes somewhere where I could find the name of the specific alternative the context refers to, apart from calling `ctx.constructor.name`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, can you add code to clarify?

Comment: edited with more details

Comment: I think it's not possible to get those names, because they are not rules as such, but just helpers.